# How to the find radius of a galaxy given its inclination?

Tags: astrophysics

If the semi major and semi minor axis of a galaxy are 3" and 1" respectively, how would you find the radius of the galaxy?

Comment: What do you mean by "radius ... given its inclination"? The semi-major and semi-minor axes are the radii of an ellipse.

Comment: When you update, please be sure to clarify units.  ' 3" ' could be inches , or seconds of arc, among others.